# Filter a list of dictionaries to always return a single dictionary, given a default key value to lookup

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm aware that there are 1001 ways of solving this solution, I'm asking the community to get an understanding of what the most Pythonic approach seems to be.

Lets say I have a list of dictionaries taking the format:

```
colours = [{"color": "green", "owner": "Mark"},
           {"color": "blue", "owner": "Luke"},
           {"color": "red", "owner": "John"}]
```

Overlooking the obvious fact that the list should be a dictionary of dictionaries, I'm wanting to retrieve a single dictionary from the list given a user input for the `color` key in the dictionary, but using a default value if the color is not matched (lets say "green" in this example).

As such I'm seeking a function:

```
def get_with_default(colour, colours, default):
```

That given the colours list would return:

```
>>> get_with_default("blue", colours, "green") # Valid dictionary
{"color": "blue", "owner": "Luke"}
>>> get_with_default("black", colours, "green") # Colour doesn't exist
{"color": "green", "owner": "Mark"}
```

**Update** (thanks Martijn), the default value would be hard-coded and known to be in the list, *however* the other key/value pairs in that dictionary are unknown/dynamic (so I know that 'green' is a key in a dictionary, but I *don't* know who 'owns' green in this simplified case

Comment: Ah, so `"green"` means the default is to use the first match for `'color': 'green'` in the input list, effectively doing a second scan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best, but nice and readable:

```
def get_with_default(colour, L, default=''):
    temp = None
    for d in L:
        if d['color'] == colour:
            return d
        elif d['color'] == default:
            temp = d
    return temp
```

When testing:

```
>>> get_with_default('blue', colours, 'green')
{'color': 'blue', 'owner': 'Luke'}
>>> get_with_default('black', colours, 'green')
{'color': 'green', 'owner': 'Mark'}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use an `elif == default` and make `d_temp` my default value which would be returned if I reach the end of my loop? Seems more inefficient to create a completely new dictionary and then find a key within it afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

[`next()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) is the most pythonic function to achieve just that:

```
def get_with_default(colour, colours, default):
    search = (d for d in colours if d['color'] in (colour, default))
    match_or_default = next(search)
    if match_or_default['color'] != default or default == colour:
        return match_or_default
    return next(search, match_or_default)
```

`next()` loops over the first argument until that produces a result, then returns that. If the first argument is exhausted, `StopIteration` is raised instead, unless a second argument is given, a default, in which case that value is returned instead of raising the exception.

By giving it a generator expression that embodies the search, you efficiently scan the `colours` list for the first match. If that turns out to be the default, then we continue to scan until we find the *other* match, or reach the end of the list.

Demo:

```
>>> get_with_default("blue", colours, "green")
{'color': 'blue', 'owner': 'Luke'}
>>> get_with_default("black", colours, "green")
{'color': 'green', 'owner': 'Mark'}
```

The above method is quite efficient in that it only has to scan the input list once, and the scan stops as soon as a match is found.

Note that this function will raise `StopIteration` if the default is not present either:

```
>>> get_with_default("black", colours, "purple")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in get_with_default
StopIteration
```

You could instead return `None` in that case by giving the first `next()` call a default return value as well:

```
match_or_default = next(search, None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit :). Also, +1 because it is the most pythonic way :p

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but I'll keep the question open for a while to see if anyone has any other approaches.

Comment: Martijn, since your edit this looks like it's maybe a worse solution? If my colour and my default were the same, I'd still end up iterating over the list twice even though I had it the first time.

Comment: @IanClark: Adjusted for that edge-case.

Comment: Martijn, thanks for that - though whilst this is very efficient in that you only search the initial list once, in my opinion it looks fairly confusing. I far preferred the readability of the try-catch approach.

Comment: @IanClark: `search` is a generator expression. It encodes the search for either the default or matching colour. `next()` will loop over it, but if a match is found, the generator just sits there until you use it again, at which point the search continues from wherever the previous match was found.

Comment: Martijn, it's not that I can't work out what's going on in your answer, but I now feel that Haidro's answer is probably the clearer of the two, is probably similar in efficiency, and similar in the number of lines.

Comment: @IanClark: They are different approaches, yes. It was your `default` requirement which was misunderstood at first, that made me pick this approach. TBH, Haidro's approach will work *better* if `default` is not *unique* in the input list; if hat is the case my version needs to be made more complicated still and I'd switch to his version too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension to achieve this.

```
def get_with_defaults(color,colours,default='green'):
    res = [col for col in colours if col['color']==color]   
    if not res:
        return [col for col in colours if col['color']==default]
    return res

get_with_defaults('blue',colours)
[{'color': 'blue', 'owner': 'Luke'}]
>>> get_with_defaults('black',colours)
[{'color': 'green', 'owner': 'Mark'}]
```

Output in dictionary.

```
def get_with_defaults(color,colours,default='green'):
    res = [col for col in colours if col['color']==color]   
    if not res:
        return [col for col in colours if col['color']==default][0]
    return res[0]

get_with_defaults('blue',colours)
{'color': 'blue', 'owner': 'Luke'}
>>> get_with_defaults('black',colours)
{'color': 'green', 'owner': 'Mark'}
```

Comment: I've proposed an edit to this as I don't want my dictionary to be nested in a list. Also, it's worth mentioning that this could throw an `IndexError` if the default doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @IanClark, But it will not throw `IndexError` if default doesn't exist.